# Bind elements of List<string> to text blocks

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to make some sort of wheel spinning. I have 5 customized text blocks, text file with the list of values (it may consist of 1-1000 items). After reading the file I have a 'List fileValues' with its values. I decided to create another 'List wheel' which will contain up to 5 elements at the time and is expected to be bind to text blocks.

When one presses a spin button, last element of 'wheel' is removed and new element from 'values' is added to the beginning of the 'wheel' list.

In order UI will be responsive to changes in the list, it is good to bind each element in the 'wheel' to corresponding text block on UI. But what I tried to do up to this moment didn't work.

Here is what I tried to do (the code is a little bit dirty, but I try to make it work firstly).

5 customized text blocks

```
<TextBlock Name="Value1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
<TextBlock Name="Value2" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
<TextBlock Name="Value3" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
<TextBlock Name="Value4" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
<TextBlock Name="Value5" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```

ObservableList which implements INotifyCollectionChanged interface

```
class ObservableList : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List<string> _valuesList;

    public string First
    {
        get { return _valuesList.First(); }
    }

    public string Last
    {
        get { return _valuesList.Last(); }
    }

    public ObservableList()
    {
        this._valuesList = new List<string>();
    }

    public string this[Int32 index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_valuesList.Count == 0 || index + 1 > _valuesList.Count)
            {
                return "------";
            }
            return _valuesList[index];
        }
    }

    public void AddLast(string value)
    {
        _valuesList.Add(value);
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged();
    }

    public void AddFirst(string value)
    {
        _valuesList.Insert(0, value);
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged();
    }

    public void RemoveFirst()
    {
        _valuesList.RemoveAt(0);
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged();
    }

    public void RemoveLast()
    {
        _valuesList.Remove(_valuesList.Last());
        OnNotifyCollectionChanged();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public void OnNotifyCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (_valuesList as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

XAML Code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<string> _values = new List<string>();
    private ObservableList _uiValues = new ObservableList();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Value1.DataContext = _uiValues[0];
        Value2.DataContext = _uiValues[1];
        Value3.DataContext = _uiValues[2];
        Value4.DataContext = _uiValues[3];
        Value5.DataContext = _uiValues[4];

    }

    private void LoadFileBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Loads text file and fills _values
    }

    private void SpinBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitUiTextBlocks();

        //Spin simulation
    }

    private void InitUiTextBlocks()
    {
        _uiValues.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        { 
            //Nothing appears on UI and CollectionChanged event is null
            _uiValues.AddLast(_values.First());
            _values.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use 'ObservableCollection', but the effect is the same. Nothing appears on UI. In fact I can't imagine how to bind each of List element to specific Label. Is it even possible to do such binding?

Comment: why don't you bind in xaml to properties p1...p5, and set them where/when you need them?

Comment: @Noctis Hm, in fact I'm still new to data binding in WPF. And the most understandable way to bind data, for me at the moment, is code-behind. Could you please recommend some sources or describe in a pair of words how it can be done in xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XAML do something like:

```
<Label Name="some_name" Content="{Binding SomeStingProperty}"/>
```

and in the code behind, have a

```
public string SomeStringProperty {get; set;}
```

you can bind to a collection as well, and if it's an `ObservableCollection` it will update on change.

search for basic XAML binding otherwise :)

(on a side note, it's cleaner i think it the XAML, i personally don't like to do it in the code behind ...)

As a side note, and totally self promoting, here are 2 articles that will probably help:

1. [Understanding selected value](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele)
2. [The big mvvm template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template).

The second might be a bit over your head if you're a beginner, but should be worth reading nevertheless.

Comment: If I correctly understand, I need to create, in my case, 5 properties which will get different elements from the List and catch exceptions (if any). The binding will be done in the XAML?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, or if you want to show the 5 in one control (label/textbox etc), you can bind to an observable collection property, and just update the collection with your five items.